# Replace all subsequent occurrences of the first character by `$`

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question for the code is 'input a word and check whether the first character of the word is repeated in the word again or not. If yes then change all the repeating characters to `$` except the first character.'

So I coded the following and used the logic to start the loop from the second character of the word so that first character remains unchanged.

```
a=input()
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    if(a[i]==a[0]):
        b=a.replace(a[i],'$')
print(b)
```

for the above program I gave the input as 'agra' and to my surprise got the output as '$gr$'. the first character was also changed.
What is the problem with my logic? and what other solution do you suggest?

Comment: Because that's what `replace` does.

Comment: There’s no point to even loop if you’re using `replace()`. Either take a substring without the first letter and replace that, or go through every character and change just that character.

Comment: FYR, _alphabet_ is an ordered set of letters. What you call an _alphabet_ is an _alphabetic character_, or simply a _letter_.

Comment: @andreytyukin Are you sure the OP means "_the first character_", not "_the first alphabetic character_"?

Comment: You apply `replace` to `a`, the entire string. The fact that you *replace* the character at `a[i]` with something else does not matter.

Comment: @DyZ I'm around 99% sure. The code does not contain any traces of control flow that could somehow react differently on various types of characters. Instead, the code contains an obvious mistake in the `replace` part. I assume that the focus of the question is on the `replace`, not on the type of character. The repeated usage of word "alphabet" looked just like wrong word choice for "character". I decided to edit it away, because it looked too strange. I could be wrong, but I have to set the threshold *somewhere*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the correct solution in python, see Stephen Rauch's answer.**

I think that what you where trying to achieve, in a very "unpythonic" way, is:

```
a = input()
b = a # b is a copy 
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] == a[0]:
        # replace i-th char of b by '$''
print (b)
```

How to do that replacement? In python: strings are *immutable*, that means you cannot replace a char "in place". Try to do this:

```
a='agra'
a[3] = '$'
```

And you'll get an error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

If you want to replace the i-th char of a string by `$`, you have to write:

```
b = b[:i] + '$' + b[i+1:]
```

That is: build a new string from `b[0]`, ..., `b[i-1]`, add a `$` and continue with `b[i+1]`, ..., `b[len(a)-1]`. If you use this in your code, you get:

```
a = input()
b = a
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] == a[0]:
        b = b[:i] + '$' + b[i+1:]
print (b)
```

Okay, it works but **don't do that because it's very "unpythonic" and inefficient**.

**BEGIN EDIT**
By the way, you don't need to replace, you can just build the string character by character:

```
a = input()
b = a[0] # start with first char
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] == a[0]:
        b += '$' # $ if equals to first char
    else:
        b += a[i] # else the current char
print (b)
```

**END EDIT**

That gave me this idea:

```
a=input()
b="".join('$' if i!=0 and c==a[0] else c for i,c in enumerate(a))
print(b)
```

Explanation: the list comprehension takes all characters of `a` along with their position `i` (that's what `enumerate` does). For every couple position, character, if the position is not `0` (not the first character) and if the character is equal to `a[0]`, then put a `$`. Else put the character itself. Glue everything together to make a new string.

Again, that's not the right way to do what you are trying to do, because there is another way that is neater and easier (see Stephen Rauch's answer), but is shows how you can sometimes handle difficulties in python.

Comment: I like the `b="".join('$' if i!=0 and c==a[0] else c for i,c in enumerate(a))` approach. The rest of the answer doesn't bring much.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I added a step between OP's trial and the list comprehension, to show the progression. My plan was to travel from OP's idea to a pythonic idea, even if a better solution exists.

Comment: Maybe OP will find that instructive. For me it's more like "TL;DR", sorry.

Answer (score 5):

That is more simply done like:

#### Code:

```
b = a[0] + a[1:].replace(a[0], '$')
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = 'stops'
b = a[0] + a[1:].replace(a[0], '$')
print(b)
```

#### Results:

```
stop$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=input()
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    if(a[i]==a[0]):
        b=a[1:len(a)].replace(a[i],'$')
print(a[0]+b)
```

you changed whole word/sentence 'a': a.replace(...)

Comment: loop is highly inefficient. It slices `a` a lot of times. no need for a loop.

Comment: yep, i tried only use author's code to show where is problem ;)

Comment: `a[1:len(a)]` is quite bad. `a[1:]` is how you do it.